# How to parse a custom url (within WP site) and obtain params passed to that URL

Tags: urls, parameter

In my WP site-- eg. http://www.mydomain.com-- a request has to be passed to a custom URL-- http://www.mydomain.com/custompage?param1=abc&param2=def

Now, I wish to obtain the parameters passed to that URL from a function in functions.php of that theme. This function is executed when the above (example) URL is loaded...

How do I do this? For above eg. I wish to obtain first parameter=abc and second parameter=def-- I already know that the parameters are named param1 and param2.

Comment: Tell us more about the 'custompage'. Like: What is the page id? Is the page already using a page template?

Answer (score 2):

First, you register your query vars `param1` and `param2`:

```
function wpse_101951_query_vars( $qv ) {
    $qv[] = 'param1';
    $qv[] = 'param2';
    return $qv;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse_101951_query_vars' );
```

To use this information, you can pretty much hook into any [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) or [filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) after `parse_query`. That's the first action available after the query vars are set, so it's the first action where you can use [get_query_var](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var). Here's an example:

```
function wpse_101951_get_params() {
    if ( $param1 = get_query_var( 'param1' ) ) {
        # Do something as a result of param1 being set
    }
    if ( $param2 = get_query_var( 'param2' ) ) {
        # Do something as a result of param2 being set
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpse_101951_get_params' );
```

Answer (score 0):

From my limited experience I would shy away from polluting WordPress's query variables without good reason. These are used when making a database query and are quite easy to mess up.

If you are not intent on changing WP's main query object, just use PHP's `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`.

```
function get_url_params() {
    if ( isset($_GET['param1']) )
        $param1 = $_GET['param1'];

    if ( isset($_GET['param2']) )
        $param2 = $_GET['param2'];
}
```